# Executing a named function after declaring it

Tags: javascript

I know that this can be done for anonymous functions

```
(function toBeExecutedImmediately() {
    // Code
}());
```

I have a function that I wish to use in other places, but should also be executed immediately. Is it possible to do it with **one statement instead of the following**? The return value isn't needed.

```
function toBeExecutedImmediately() {
    // Code
};

toBeExecutedImmediately();
```

Comment: The first one isn't an anonymous function. It has a name.

Comment: You have it solved, you just have to try it.

Comment: @wared: No, the name `toBeExecutedImmediately` will not be added to the containing scope, so it won't be available elsewhere.

Comment: No, because you can't combine a function declaration and an expression (which bypasses the declaration).

Comment: The last snippet is how you're supposed to do that in javascript. What exactly is wrong about it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I saw that, yet... I wasn't referring to first code snippet as wared, but the second. I guess I misinterpreted since xiankai is looking for an alternative. Yet, why? I don't see anything wrong with declaring and then calling, it is not like some code will get injected there without notice [as in: multi-threading javascript is hack], right? It is either a weird enviroment or academic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it with one statement instead of the following?

No. As you've found, the named function expression (your first example) doesn't add the name to the containing scope *(except on [broken engines](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) — I'm looking at you, IE8 and earlier)*, so you can't call the function elsewhere without doing something to make that possible, and of course with the function *declaration* (your second example), you have to give the name twice.

Your best bet is probably to just go ahead and do the declaration and the separate call (your second example).

We could probably come up with something convoluted that would technically meet the definition of "a single statement," but it's unlikely to be shorter.

If brevity is your goal, this is two statements, but brief:

```
var f = function() {
    // Code
}, toBeExecutedImmediately = f;
f();
```

But while relatively brief, I'd say clarity suffers. :-)

Of course, anything is possible if you add a helper function. For instance:

```
// The helper
function defineAndExecute(f) {
    f();
    return f;
}

// using it
var toBeExecutedImmediately = defineAndExecute(function() {
    // Do work here
});
```

The function is technically anonymous, but you can call it via the `var`. (You could use a named function expression here too, but of course that would defeat the goal — not repeating the name — as I understand it.)

---

Side note: Your first example is not "an anonymous function". The function has a proper name, it's a *named* function expression. It's just that with named function expressions, unlike function declarations, that name isn't added to the containing scope.

Comment: I didn't know about the *broken engines* part, that is interesting!

Comment: @xiankai: Yeah, IE8 and earlier **really** get named function expressions wrong, details: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html They actually create two different functions, at different times.

Comment: This is a great answer. Please add a name to the anonymous function in the `toBeExecutedImmediately` var in your second example *(same as the var name, just like a function declaration)*.

Comment: @JoeSimmons: Thanks. I left the name off because I think the goal is to avoid duplicating it.

Comment: You wouldn't duplicate it, since it's not a function declaration. It just adds a name property to the function.

Comment: @JoeSimmons: By "duplicate" I meant "type it twice".

Comment: I see. In that case, you should add a note to say you **could** use a named function expression.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a namespace :

```
// alerts "say yes"
(window.say = function (s) { alert('say ' + s); })('yes');
// alerts "say something"
say('something');
```

As a reply to the comments, here is how to make the function local :

```
(function(){
    var dontSay;
    // alerts "don't say no"
    (dontSay = function (s) { alert('don\'t say ' + s); })('no'); 
    // alerts "don't say anything"
    dontSay('anything');
})();
```

@JoeSimmons It's not a revolution indeed, but the question is also not really essential ;D

Comment: What if you don't want a global function?

Comment: @JoeSimmons Just use a local namespace :)

Comment: .... really? Obviously I know that. What if I DON'T want a global function. What if I want to define a `say` function inside another function's scope? There is no namespace for that accessible from inside the language.

Comment: Oh, I see... deleting your replies to make me look like a fool instead of you. lol.

Comment: @JoeSimmons I'm sorry, I've misread your first comment, I've updated my reply accordingly. That said, I understand your annoyance, this solution is obviously not a best practice :)

Comment: @JoeSimmons That was my best shot :/

Answer (score 1):

You can write sort of "function builder" like this:

```
function DeclareAndExecute(name, func) {
    window[name] = func;
    func();
}
```

Usage:

```
DeclareAndExecute("toBeExecutedImmediately", function() {
    //code here
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/3xubB/).

This will add the function to the global `window` scope using the given name and insta-execute it.

Comment: Well, sure. It's possible to create something that doesn't rely on the function being global, too.